# Run only certain tests in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, mstest

I have inherited an ASP.Net (Non .Net Core) project with a large amount of tests all contained in one C# test project.  I want to run the unit tests on Azure DevOps as a build step but the issue I face is that the unit tests are inside a sub-folder of the project and in other folders are other tests that I do not wish to run.

My question is, can I configure the `task: VSTest@2` to only run the tests inside a specified folder within the Tests project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have control over what parameters are passed to `vstest.console`? Then you could just use those to configure which tests to run.

Comment: I do have full control over the parameters but I have no idea which parameters to use and how to use them.

Comment: Did you consider using TestCategoryAttribute? Refer the article https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2018/07/organizing-test-cases.aspx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In you build yaml file (or via the azure devops interface) you can set:

`testFiltercriteria:ClassName~MyTestClassName`

You could try seeing whether wildcards work in this to allow you to say everything in x folder. The documentation for this property is quite sparse.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) for a list of the full set of properties available to VSTest@2.

See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/filter.md) for documentation on the test case filters that can be applied.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/jj155796(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for a list of the additional command line options (not needed for this, but a useful resource.)

Alternatively, the testFiltercriteria can be used to specify the FullyQualifiedName (name including namespace). Filtering by this, you can use "~" to say contains rather than equals, so if your folder structure roughly matches your namespace structure, then this would also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a input box for applying filters in the Pipeline Step for 'Visual Studio Test' in your Azure DevOps Pipeline. [image: screenshot]